# prineside.tdi / infinitode Progress.xml decode

Tags: android

i don't know if what i am about to post is the right plece to post, but, here i go :)

So, i was wondering, how can i decode this:

```
<string name="dailyQuestsCompleted">'4:|</string>
```

In this post https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/5vm9yr/i_can_only_decrypt/ (where i cannot post any new answer) someone was saying that it is, and quote " The obfuscation is device dependant though."

The full text reads:

> ```
> I got it. Decompiled the apk and translated the algorithm to python: http://pastebin.com/m11r2Lqt. The obfuscation is device
> ```
>
> dependant though. Variable k in the script is your device's
> Secure.ANDROID_ID. Easiest way to get it would be to enable USB
> debugging in your phone's settings, install SDK Platform Tools and run
> the following command:
>
> ```
> adb shell settings get secure android_id
> ```

I got python, i have the Secure.ANDROID_ID but further then that, i don't know what to do.

Would be nice if i would get some advice, for research purposes, of course :)

I'm just curious about how is transformed this code: `<string name="money">,(&amp;xh4=``

From a text/imge to the code above ...

Thank you.